# I want to generate lat-long in Google sheet when Address is given as input. How can that be done?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm interested to generate lat-long (rounded off to 6 digits) in 2 different columns considering Address/placeName as input in Google sheet.

For Ex:

```
Input column:   Address: Tajmahal, Agra

Result column:  Lattitude: 27.175014, Longitude: 78.042152
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add this script to your sheet:**

```
function GEOCODE(input) {
    input = encodeURI(input)
    var options = {"method": "get"};
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=" + input + "&results=1&lang=en-US", options);
    var result = JSON.parse(response);
  try {
    result = result.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.Point.pos
    return result;
  } catch(err) {
    return ""
  }
}
```

**and then use:**

```
=SPLIT(GEOCODE(G25), " ")
```

[image]